# Is it possible to delete all entities from CloudTable without round-trip them?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to delete all entities without round-trip them?
If this could be done only by deleting/restoring the table, what methods should be used to save schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to delete all entities without round-trip them?

In order to delete an entity, you would need both `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` for that. If you know these values for all entities, you could simply delete the entities without fetching them first.

> If this could be done only by deleting/restoring the table, what
>   methods should be used to save schema?

You could certainly delete the table to delete all entities. Please do remember that Azure table storage is `schema-less` so there is no need (or a way) to preserve the schema.

**However one word of caution regarding deleting tables**:

What I have found that when you delete a table, table storage service sends you a message back that the table is deleted however depending on your size of the table, it may take a little while for the table to be actually deleted. During that time, you won't be able to perform any operations on that table.

Comment: What are another objects that could be deleted together with table and that should be restored after recreating it... may be some security options?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you describe it in more details please? Thanks.

Comment: I afraid to delete the table because I do not know all consequences... Especially I afraid that Create will not restore deleted table in its previous configuration. Possibly I should just try...

Comment: Once you delete the table, all data is gone. For your peace of mind, you could possibly download the data first on your local computer and then proceed with delete.